# Create Delay Before Typing "No Results Found" to Screen

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to print a "No Results Found" message if a user's search query finds no results in my Angular2 app. I am also trying to delay this from happening because there is a delay set on the search query evaluation itself, and right now "No Results Found" prints to the screen for a millisecond, while the delay on the query happens. Then the "No Results Found" disappears while the query is evaluated, and then reappears if no results are indeed found. So the issue is that millisecond printing of the message to the screen prematurely because of the delay set on the query. I have tried wrapping the function in a timeout to match the delay, like this:

```
setTimeout(noResultsFound, 2000);

    noResultsFound(): boolean 
    {
        if (this.query && !this.hasResults) {
        return true;
    }
```

And my view code is like this:

```
<div *ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound" class="no-results-found">No Results Found</div>
```

But it's not working, and I'm getting an error message saying "Function declaration my be 'setTimeout". Is this something you can't do in Typescript? Is there an alternative? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
 setTimeout(noResultsFound, 2000);
 noResultsFound(): boolean
```

Has a few things wrong:

- `noResultsFound` is not a global. Its a class member. Thus you need `this` e.g. `setTimeout(this.noResultsFound, 2000);`.
- If you use `this` you need to be aware of its issues (its a JavaScript thing). Recommend an arrow so `noResultsFound(): boolean` becomes `noResultsFound = (): boolean =>`. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html
- Don't use `setTimeout` for debouncing. Use a better functional approach e.g. `underscore.debounce`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, ignoring the delay issue for a moment, this code works:

    public get noResultsFound(): boolean
    {
        if (this.query && !this.hasResults) {
            return true;
        }
    }


How would you recommend I create a delay in this situation?